# Letter Templates in Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: templates, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

**How can I populate Letter templates with specific

fields in MS Dynamics CRM 2013**?

Comment: Have you tried something? Please add code here.

Comment: Actually i've tried but documents templates are not present in MS Dynamics CRM 2013.

Answer (score 1):

It's not my favourite option, but in CRM2013 you could use Mail Merge.

You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2ibr0MP_5o) to have an idea of how this feature works.

[Here](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/colinmaitland/2014/02/04/how-to-create-a-mail-merge-template-for-a-custom-mail-merge-enabled-entity-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013) is a good tutorial which explains how to create the mail merge template. Bearing in mind that the Mail Merge button is no longer available in the command bar, you might found this helpful too: [Restore hidden buttons](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/archive/2013/09/06/how-to-restore-a-hidden-button-on-the-crm-2013-command-bar).

Comment: can i send a letter to my client through mail merge templates?

Comment: After finishing the mail merge process you will end with a Word document which you can attach to an email, print or whatever you want. Keep in mind that this document won't be generated in the "CRM context", so you will need to manually upload if it's required.